# How do I change Synology DSM 5.0 http port via SSH?

Tags: ssh, nas, port, synology

I need to change port for HTTP from 5000 to 7777 on my Synology NAS via SSH. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option for that in your synology configuration gui/web interface.

Depending on your synology version it might be in different places.

I woudn't recommend to do that over ssh as synolgy reads the configuration from an xml file and generates the service config files dynamically during boot which are then stored on a tmpfs mount.